# How to use member of one class in another class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class:

```
class Cave 
{
private:
    int no_of_rooms;

public:
    vector<int>rooms;
    Cave(int r);
    Cave(){};
};
```

The constructor of Cave fills the vector rooms with random integers:

```
Cave::Cave(int r)
    :no_of_rooms{ r }
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i<no_of_rooms)
    {
        rooms.push_back(randint(1, no_of_rooms));
        ++i;
    }   
}
```

I create another class:

```
class Player : public Cave
{
public:
    Player(int *plyr) 
        :p_ptr{ plyr }
    { 
        plyr = &rooms[0];
    }

private:
    int* p_ptr = nullptr;

};
```

This Player class seems to be a mess. I am trying to get access to the same rooms vector filled up by the Cave constructor.

Comment: `class Player : public Cave` in OO design, this reads as "A Player is a Cave".  That seems strange.

Comment: "`class Player : public Cave`" strikes me as rather odd. Public inheritance models a *is a* relationship and it seems weird to say that a Player *is a* Cave.

Comment: i meant it as : a player is in a cave and needs to access the rooms of the cave

Comment: Post a complete program, a [MCVE]. If someone who wants to help needs to test the code, don't ask them to assemble it from fragments, add headers, create a main(), etc...

Comment: @user539249 If "player is in a cave" that smells of encapsulation and not inheritance. Taking what Yakk said; "player is a cave" then yes, inheritance is the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you really should encapsulate Cave and not inherit from it. Try this.

cave.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>

class Cave 
{
private:
    int no_of_rooms;

public:
    std::vector<int>rooms;
    Cave(int r);
    Cave(){};
};

inline int randint(int min, int max) 
{
    std::random_device device;
    std::mt19937 engine(device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(min, max);
    return dist(engine);
}
```

cave.cpp

```
#include "cave.h"

Cave::Cave(int r)
    :no_of_rooms{ r }
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i<no_of_rooms)
    {
        rooms.push_back(randint(1, no_of_rooms));
        ++i;
    }   
}
```

player.h

```
#include "cave.h"

class Player// : public Cave
{
public:
    Player(int *plyr) 
        :p_ptr{ plyr }
    { 
        cave = Cave(*plyr);
        plyr = &cave.rooms[0];
    }

private:
    Cave cave;
    int* p_ptr = nullptr;

};
```

I tried it using

```
#include "player.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int player_count = 2;
    Player p(&player_count);
}
```

Also, I am not sure the unnecessary use of pointers in some of your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i can sleep well

Comment: @user539249 glad it did help.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a typo:

```
plyr = &rooms[0];
```

This sets the function argument, not the member.

You meant `p_ptr = &rooms[0];`?

But then why have a function argument at all. This makes no sense.

Unfortunately, you did not get around to telling us what you want to do, or what you want these classes to do, or what input you need to provide to the classes. So I cannot answer any further.

Comment: yeah i meant p_ptr = &rooms[0];

Comment: Once the cave is created, i want the Player object to be able to point to the vector<int>rooms .

Comment: @user539249: Why? It already contains that vector, by inheritance.